# Datagridview excessive memory usage

Tags: winforms, memory, datagridview

I have an unbound datagridview with 175 columns and 50,000 rows, populated primarily with doubles.  According to my calculations, this equates to a memory usage of 175*50000*8 bytes = 70 MB.  However, Task Manager says the grid is using about 1.2 GB of memory - an 17x overhead!  Can anyone explain why it's consuming so much memory?

From the msdn article on scaling the datagridview ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ha5xt0d9.aspx ) I don't think I'm doing anything flagrantly wrong.  I'm not setting styles or contextmenustrips for individual cells.  No modifications other than populating the cell values and setting format strings on column level.

I understand that virtual mode or shared rows might decrease memory consumption, but given my above calculations, I don't think it should be necessary.  17x overhead doesn't sound right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that each cell of your DataGridView holds a [DataGridViewCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.aspx) instance, containing about [33 properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell_properties).  It's more overhead than just a `double` value.

Comment: So even if I switch from unbound to bound, it won't do much since the cells will still have all those properties?  Could virtual mode fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation is based on the System.Double containing 8 bytes.  There may be 8 bytes in the value of each cell in the underlying System.Data.DataTable, but that does not mean that the same amount of data in the DataGridView is only 8 bytes.

Each and every cell has multiple properties - height, width, borderstyle, bordercolor, etc.  Even if these all are at the default values, those default values consume memory.